# How do I compare values in dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

Currently I'm working on a little project and I keep running into trouble with this code.

```
import xmlrpclib
import glob
import os
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

# keep track of all files in directory
fileList = {} 

# Search for all files in directory
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    fileList[file] = "closed"

def openFile(filename):
    if filename in fileList.keys(): # Check if file exists
        value = fileList.get(filename)
        if value == 'closed'          # If closed then open
            fileList[filename] = open(filename, 'r+b')
            return "File open"
        else                          # File must have been open
            return "File is already open"
    else                            # File doesn't exist, create one
        # if file not found
        fileList[filename] = open(filename, 'w') # Create file
        return "File created"

def closeFile(filename):
    if filename in fileList.keys(): # Check if file exists
        fileList[filename].close()    # close file
        fileList[filename] = 'closed' # Change value
        return "File closed"
    else
    return "file does not exist"

def readFile(filename):              
    if filename in fileList.keys():    # Check if file exists
        return fileList[filename].read() # Return contents
    else
        return "File does not exist"

def writeFile(filename, content):
    if filename in fileList.keys():     # Check if file exists
        fileList[filename].write(content) # Write content to file
        return "Wrtie successful"
    else
        return "File does not exist"

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000)) # Giving server a port
print "Listening on port 8000..."
server.register_function(openFile,'openFile')
server.register_function(closeFile,'closeFile')
server.register_function(readFile, 'readFile')
server.register_function(writeFile, 'writeFile')
server.serve_forever()
```

For some reason I keep getting:

```
File "server.py", line 16
    if value == 'closed'          # If closed then open
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As you can see the syntax is wrong but I have no idea why and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to remove the comment but I get the same error message with the arrow pointing at the last character in the if statement.

I'm new with python but have a year experience with Java so if this also happens in Java I would probably understand it better in Java terminology.

Comment: You get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` because the syntax is not correct or, in Java terminology, the syntax is not correct. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the colon:

```
if value == 'closed':
                    ^-----colon
```